# Excel: Count if value is at least once in sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a excel formula solution to find references of a keyword in all existing sheets.
[image: image showing an example from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2541-excel-countif-across-multiple-worksheets.html]
The expected result I'm looking for is 3 instead of 4. Because the keyword Excel has been found at least once in every sheet.

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&C2:C4&"'!A2:A6"),E2))` Instead of this formula, thats returns the result 4.

Comment: Try `=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&C2:C4&"'!A2:A6"),E2)>0))`

Comment: genius, can you please explain the --?

Comment: If you previously counted all values on all sheets, then adding `COUNTIF (...)> 0` will return `TRUE` only to sheets that have at least one cell that matches the criteria, `FALSE` for the rest. While `--` converts the bool value to a number (`FALSE` = 0, `TRUE` = 1). `SUMPRODUCT` sums up `1` values

Comment: I see, so `--` is some kind of casting conecpt. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,E2)>0)+(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,E2)>0)+(COUNTIF(Sheet3!A:A,E2)>0)
```

Where **E2** contains the word *Excel*.

Comment: this one is technically also correct. The mentioned formula in the OPs comment `Try =SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&C2:C4&"'!A2:A6"),E2)>0))` by basic works dynamically for any sheet. That's why I would prefere that one